# SQL Query - Combining Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have listed below the queries I've ran and the expected and actual results. I think the issue has something to do with the combination of filters in the WHERE clause - I would like the results from the first two queries in one table with two columns essentially.

- Expected output : 28 ; actual output : 28

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(t.Id) 
  FROM teams AS t
  WHERE teamStatusId = 339 AND live = 1
  ```
- Expected output : 1; actual output : 1

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(p.Id) 
  FROM Players AS p
  INNER JOIN teams AS t ON t.TeamId = p.Id
  WHERE teamStatusId = 339 AND isInjuired = 1
  ```
- Expected output 28 | 1 ; actual output : 30 | 30

  ```
  SELECT 
      COUNT(p.Id) AS 'Players', 
      COUNT(t.Id) AS 'Team'
  FROM 
      Players AS p
  INNER JOIN
      Teams AS t ON p.TeamId = t.Id 
  WHERE
      teamStatusId = 339 
      AND p.isInjuired = 1  
      AND t.live = 1
  ```

Comment: Does a player belong to multiple teams? Looking at your query, if that situation exists, that will quickly throw off your counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your count nos will grow if the one player belongs to multiple team in that case you need `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.Id) AS 'Players', COUNT(DISTINCT t.Id) AS 'Team'
FROM Players as p INNER JOIN
     Teams t 
     ON p.TeamId = t.Id 
WHERE teamStatusId = 339 AND p.isInjuired = 1 AND t.live = 1;
```